# Android: Changing the windowBackground of PreferenceActivity causes weird effect

Tags: android, transparency, drawable, preferenceactivity

I want to add a background image to my preference activity.
I tried by creating custom Theme:

```
<style name="MyPreference" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/preference_background</item>
</style>
```

and in the Manifest:

```
<activity android:name="SettingsActivity" android:theme="@style/MyPreference">
...        
</activity>
```

But for some reason that caused to the PreferenceScreen to have a transparent background, like that:
[image]

Any idea how can i overcome that?

Comment: Have you tried setting `android:background`?